# Dynamically Created Button With ID Does Not Run Function

Tags: jquery

I have a button that gets created after clicking the initial button, `logoff`, on the page. It then puts up a new button with the id of `resetelite`. When I click this button nothing happens, it won't see the function. I used the .on to reattach an event handler, not sure if I did this right:

```
...
        <dt>
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Log Off" class="btn btn-default" id="logoff" />
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <br />
    <table class="table" style="white-space: nowrap" id="results">

    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="button">

</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
<script>
    $('#logoff').click(function (event) {
        var SessionId = $('#SessionId').val();
        var ServerName = $('#ServerName').val();
        var AppName = $('#AppName').val();
        $(this).remove();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "sessionid":"' + SessionId + '","servername":"' + ServerName + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/LogOffSession",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            var html = "Logoff Failed"
            var err = "<tr><td>" + data.ErrorMessage + "</td></tr>"
            var btn = "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Reset Profile\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"resetelite\" />"

            if (err.length > 0) {
                $('#results').append($(err));

                $('#button').append($(btn));
            } else {
                $('#results').append($(html));
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "resetelite", function (event) {
            var UserId = $('#UserId').val();
            $(this).remove();
            lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "username":"' + UserId + '" }');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ResetElite",
                data: lookfor,
            }).done(function (data) {
                var html = "<tr><td>" + data.Result + "</td></tr>"
                $('#results').html("");
                $('#results').append($(html));

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `on("click", "resetelite"`  looks like a bad selector to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on("click", "resetelite",` is incorrect. It should be `.on("click", "#resetelite",`

You're using event delegation properly (hooray!) but you left out the `#` needed to select by ID.

Comment: Thanks! I'll click the check when it lets me.